# how to use @DataJpaTest with multiple datasourse

Tags: spring-boot

I tried to write integration test using annotation @DataJpaTest .
I have two datasource: Primary and secondary (class config)
in result i have an error:

```
expected single matching bean but found 2: primaryDataSource,secondary
```

then i tried to add a annotation

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.AUTO_CONFIGURED)
```

and  With AUTO_CONFIGURED only DataSources configured by properties will be replaced but instead embedded h2 i saw `Dialect    : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`

how using `@DataJpaTest` with multiple datasources ?

```
public class DataSourcesConfig {


    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondary")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have a @Primary configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.something"}
)
public class APrimaryDBDBConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.hikari")
    public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
        return dataSourceProperties()
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    @Profile("!test")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com")
                .persistenceUnit("some_persistence_unit")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Later, in my repository test classes:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Import(APrimaryDBDBConfiguration.class)
```

Finally, my test properties have:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible solution [here](https://medium.com/@joeclever/integration-testing-multiple-datasources-in-spring-boot-and-spring-data-with-spock-f88e1428ce9f).

Basically you manually configure the H2 database appropriately instead of letting Spring do it automatically.

Create an application.properties file in “src/test/resources” with the following content

```
# Let Spring autodetect the different SQL Dialects of each datasource
spring.jpa.database=default
# Generate the DB schema in the In-Memory H2 databases based on the JPA Entities
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

# H2 In-Memory Database "foo" (used in tests instead of a real PostgreSQL DB)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:foo;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

# H2 In-Memory Database "bar" (used in tests instead of a real PostgreSQL DB)
bar.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:bar;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
bar.datasource.username=sa
bar.datasource.password=
bar.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Comment: This is not really helpful. How do you build the `bar` datasource? And using `@SpringBootTest` is not a slice testing since it loads all application context

Comment: Spring itself will create the datasource for you, based on the naming convention of the properties above. If you don't like @SpringBootTest, then you can use @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and other Spring annotations (e.g. @ContextConfiguration) to control what parts of your app are included in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have h2 database added as dependency in test scope. If not, add and try:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```